# How to show all results except the first one?

Tags: database, sqlite, select

I'm using sqlite3 and this would be pretty easy if it supported TOP syntax but it does not so is there any way to output all the results/records/rows of a select minus the first result in sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table limit 10000000 offset 1
```

You have to specify a limit, but if you specify it high, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE
MINUS
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE LIMIT 1,1
```